# keychain prompt dialog when building in xcode

Tags: xcode, macos

I have just started using xcode 4.3.2 on lion (switched from snow leopard) and i can't get rid of keychain prompt on every build xcode does for device (simulator is build without prompting).
I have added keychain item in keychain access for xcode under login, but it doesn't seem to help.

thx for your help

Comment: can anyone point me to right direction ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up repairing OS X, goo thing it is lion and recovering is easy :)